# What are the disadvantages of making multiple ajax calls from a single button

Tags: jquery, single-page-application

Because I'm writing a single page app with Forms Authentication, I need to authenticate the user with one call, and then make another call to collect a partial MVC view.

I have a feeling this is generally bad practice, but I can't see any alternative.

What are the disadvantages from making a second call from within the complete function of a JQuery post?

Comment: If your second call requires authentication, it requires the first call to complete.  You may as well leave it as a single call because it needs to process synchronously.

Comment: I think it'd be a worse idea to pack two unrelated calls into one unless you have a good reason for it.  This is not a good fit for stack overflow though,  because it's too open ended

Comment: Thanks. I was worried about the "subjective" tag being applied, so instead of asking whether its bad practice, I asked what were the disadvantages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly valid as long as the partial view in your second call is not dependent of the results of the user authentication which doesn't really sound like something you'd really want to do.

I would personally make a call to authenticate the user which redirects to a partial view dependant on whether the authentication fails or passes.

Comment: It probably is, you have to wait for the logon to finish since the call to get the partial probably requires you to be logged in

Comment: true, the partial view requires the user to be authenticated, and because I'm setting the form auth cookie on the first call, the first call cannot return the view and have the user principal populated.

Comment: I would tend to shy away from loading (any) content until you know you're going to need it.